# refresh dataTable after table update

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I got a html table `tabDevis`:

```
<table id="tabDevis" class="invisible stripe">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>numDevis</th>
            <th>libProduit</th>
            <th>codEtat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I put some data with ajax call. These data are from a database. With code is inside a function :

```
function putDevis() {
  var listeDevis = $("#tabDevis").find("tbody");

  var request = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/services/opp/getDevis/",
    cache : false
  });

  request.done(function(msg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        var devis = msg[i];
        var tr = $("#template").clone();
        tr.removeAttr("id");
        tr.attr('id', 'devis-' + devis.id);
        tr.find('#numDevis').html(devis.idOpportunite);
        tr.find("#codProduit").html(devis.codProduit);
        tr.find("#libProduit").html(devis.libProduit);

        listeDevis.append(tr);
    }
  }

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Deal with the error
  }

  // Call dataTable
  $('#tabDevis').DataTable({
    "order" : [ [ 1, "desc" ] ],
    "oLanguage" : {
         ...
    }
    "aoColumns" : [ {
            "bSortable" : true
        }, {
            "bSortable" : true
        }, {
            "bSortable" : true
    }]
  }
}
```

I delete a row in my database from another way, so I want to reload the html table. I call my `putDevis()` function, but I still get the deleted row who is deleted from the database.

This delete action is done with another javasript function :

```
function deleteDevis(numDevis){

  var requestsup = $.ajax({type: "GET",
        url: "/services/ep/deleteDevis?pId=" + numDevis
        cache: false
  });

  requestsup.done(function(msg){
    putDevis();
  });

  requestsup.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Deal with errors
  });
}
```

What is the way to refresh the dataTable ?

I've tried to call `$('#tabDevis').dataTable().fnDestroy();` just before my putDevis()` call but it doesn't work.

**EDIT ABOUT SOLUTION**

The way is to destroy dataTable just there :

```
var table = $('#tabDevis').DataTable(); 
table.destroy();
var listeDevis = $("#tabDevis").find("tbody");
```

And then draw it after the dataTable call :

```
var table = $('#tabDevis').DataTable(); 
table.draw();
```

Comment: *$('#tabDevisClient')* isn't this use different element ID than the one you used to initialize the data table *$('#tabDevis')* ? Does the element with *#tabDevisClient* ID exist on your HTML page?

Comment: Edit the question, it's well tabDevis in the both case

Answer (score 0):

You Can use some thing like this:

```
var refreshinterval = 30000;
setInterval(putDevis, refreshinterval);
```

Comment: I need to refresh just when user delete a row from database (this is done with another ajax call)

Comment: when that another ajax call happens? on what event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the table and again draw it.

see this link for reference.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()

Comment: I tried `$('#tabDevis').dataTable().clear();` and hot an error as clear can't be called on this object.